# What the url anchor do for baidu search engine?

Tags: http, url, anchor, fiddler

I am exposed to HTTP for several days, and today I encounter a problem as regards baidu search engine. Details as follow:

As I open http://www.baidu.com/ with desktop browser and type in some keyword, then press ENTER, the browser url displayed is something like `http://www.baidu.com/#wd=stackoverflow&ie=utf-8` with `stackoverflow` as the search keyword.

Please notice the anchor **#wd** here. It seems pretty strange to me though, eg. as to Google for example, it would be something like `https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow` without any anchor.

I use Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the HTTP packet interaction, and curiously found something like `GET /s?ie=utf-8&wd=linux HTTP/1.1` after several HTTP packet interaction.

In the whole process, the server only responses `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and there is no stuff like `HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily` etc.

So how could it finally redirect to `GET /s?ie=utf-8&wd=linux HTTP/1.1`, what does the browser do to the anchor **#wd**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After a conversation with a front-end guy, he told me it's something about **Async Javascript** ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component of the url after the `#` sign is called the URL Fragment. It is not directly sent to the server as a part of the HTTP request (which is why you don't see it in Fiddler); it is only accessible by the JavaScript running on the page.

Some sites use URL fragments when they've used AJAX techniques to populate a page; see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/17/url-fragments-and-redirects-anchor-hash-missing.aspx for some discussion.

Comment: Much thanks for your info! Why the Baidu search engine defaultly use `#wd=keyword`instead of `s?q=keyword` just like what Google do? Is there any benefit from doing so?

Comment: Google also can use the `https://www.google.com/#q=yourqueryhere` syntax, depending on what settings you have configured. The value in using `#` instead of `?` is that the fragment syntax allows all processing to happen using AJAX on the client, while any change to the value after the `?` requires a browser navigation. The benefit of using a query string (`?`) is that it works without JavaScript enabled.